# Implementar localstorage en un servicio

Tags: angular, local-storage

estoy realizando una web bilenguaje y ya con ayuda de ustedes pude logar crear un servicio que comunique mi componente principal con el resto para traducir los textos al cambiar el idioma.

Esto me ha sido muy útil, pero al cambiar entre componentes el valor de la variable se pierde y vuelven a su idioma default.

Tambien me pasa esto al actualizar la página.

Entonces me decidí a guardar el valor de la variable cambiaidiomas en un LocalStorage. Hice testeos mediante Vanille-JS y todo perfecto pero al realizarlo sobre Angular no he sido capaz de hacerlo a través del servicio.

Actualmente tengo esto:

idioma.service.ts:

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class IdiomaService {
  private euskera = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  setIdioma(euskera:any){
    this.euskera.emit(euskera);
    localStorage.setItem("euskera", euskera);
  }
  
  getIdioma(){
    return this.euskera;
  }
}
```

App.component.ts:

```
euskera: any;


  constructor(private service : IdiomaService){
    this.euskera = false;

    this.service.setIdioma(this.euskera);
  }

  setEuskera(){
    this.euskera=true;
    this.service.setIdioma(this.euskera);
    var showLanguages = $("#language");
    showLanguages.css('opacity', '0');
  }
  setCastellano(){
    this.euskera=false;
    this.service.setIdioma(this.euskera);
    this.esconderLenguajes();
    var showLanguages = $("#language");
    showLanguages.css('opacity', '0');
  }
```

Y en Home.component.ts:

```
  euskera: any;
  constructor(service : IdiomaService) { 
    service.getIdioma().subscribe( (e: boolean) => {
      this.euskera = e
    });
    
  }
```

He intentado pasarlo mediante un método por el servicio pero no lo he logrado. También lo he intentado pasar actualmente mediante el setIdioma pero al hacer un console.log desde HOME me sale como null.

¿Alguien me puede explicar como podría hacerlo y me puede ayudar?

Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega un constructor al servicio y ahí lee el `localStorage`, luego llama el método `next()` para publicar el valor leído.

```
  import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class IdiomaService {
    
      private euskera : BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
      
      constructor(){
    
        let euskera = localStorage.getItem("euskera");
        // instanciar objeto BehaviorSubject
        // y pasar como argumento el valor booleano de euskera
        this.euskera = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(euskera == 'true');
        
        
      }
    
      setIdioma(euskera:any){
        this.euskera.next(euskera);
        localStorage.setItem("euskera", euskera);
      }
      
      getIdioma(){
        return this.euskera;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hola @Lobos, gracias por tu ayuda de nuevo, amigo. Había probado antes a agregar el contructor e intentar leer de ahí el localstorage con el emit pero no me funcionó. Acabo de intentarlo de nuevo tal y como me lo pusiste pero aun así no me funciona. Algo me estoy quedando seguro.

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta, parece que el problema era tratar los valores del localStorage directamente como bool y no como cadena.

Comment: Hola de nuevo amigo @Lobos. He probado como me dijiste pero por algún motivo me sigue sin funcionar. Al hacer un typeof ambos los trata como string pero al refrescar la página los valores del otro idioma siguen sin setearse. Se vuelven a poner, como siempre, los default.

Comment: Logré que funcionara llamando la función `emit()`  dentro de un timeout. Actualicé la respuesta para que veas el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lobos. Ahora sí. Pero ocurre algo curioso. He estado haciendo pruebas. Al pasarlo como  me dijiste, por el constructor al recargar la página se ve aplicado pero al moverme entre componentes no. Al pasarlo por el método de GetIdioma al moverme en componentes sí se aplica pero al actualizar ya no. Curioso cuanto menos jajaja. A ver si me pudieras ayudar a solucionar esto. He probado poniendo en ambos pero no funciona..

Comment: Vale xD. Probemos de otra forma, actualicé el servicio para usar `BehaviorSubject` en lugar de `EventEmitter`. Prueba de esa forma.

Comment: hola amigo, me pasa exactamente igual que antes. Después de probar con Behavior al cambiar entre componentes se queda el idioma aplicado pero al recargar la página se pone el idioma Default. No sé qué puede estar fallando :(

Comment: Antes con eventemitter me pasaba al revés, al actualizar se mantenía pero al intercambiar entre componentes no. Cuando yo lo puse en get idioma haciendo pruebas me paso lo mismo que con Behavior, entre componentes funcionaba pero al recargar no

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113391/discussion-between-lobos-and-adromicfms).